# How to find all rows of items that have a part in common using LINQ?

Tags: linq

I need to return all records (items) that has a part (X) so I can use that in a group or .GroupBy afterwards

Using this summary data:

```
ItemName PartName
1        A
1        B
2        A
3        C
```

So Item1 has two parts (A,B), etc...

I need a LINQ query that will
- find all items that have part A (i.e items 1 and 2)
- return all rows for all these items

```
1        A
1        B
2        A
```

Notice that the end result returned the row (1 B) because Item1 has PartA and so I need to get back all rows for Item1.

I was looking at something like:

```
let items = from data in summary where data.PartName == A select new { data.ItemName }  // to get all the items I need
```

But then, now that I have that list I need to use it to get all the rows for all items listed, and I can't seem to figure it out ...

Actual Source Code (for reference):
NOTE:
Recipe = ITEM
Ingredient = PART
(I was just trying to make it simpler)

```
            ViewFullRecipeGrouping = (
                from data in ViewRecipeSummary
                group data by data.RecipeName into recipeGroup
                let fullIngredientGroups = recipeGroup.GroupBy(x => x.IngredientName)
                select new ViewFullRecipe()
                {
                    RecipeName = recipeGroup.Key,
                    RecipeIngredients = (
                        from ingredientGroup in fullIngredientGroups
                        select new GroupIngredient()
                        {
                            IngredientName = ingredientGroup.Key
                        }
                    ).ToList(),
                    ViewGroupRecipes = (
                        from data in ViewRecipeSummary

                        // this is where I am looking to add the new logic to define something I can then use within the next select statement that has the right data based on the information I got earlier in this query.
                        let a = ViewRecipeSummary.GroupBy(x => x.RecipeName)
                            .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.IngredientName == recipeGroup.Key))
                            .Select(g => new ViewRecipe()
                                {
                                    RecipeName = g.Key,
                                    IngredientName = g.Select(x => x.IngredientName)
                                })                                                                  

                        select new GroupRecipe()
                        {
            // use the new stuff here

                        }).ToList(),
                }).ToList();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
var data = /* enumerable containing rows in your table */;
var part = "X";
var items = new HashSet<int>(data
    .Where(x => x.PartName == part)
    .Select(x => x.ItemName));
var query = data.Where(x => items.Contains(x.ItemName));
```

If I understand your comment at the end, I believe this also does what you want:

```
var query = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemName)
    .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.PartName == part))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ItemName = g.Key,
        PartNames = g.Select(x => x.PartName)
    });
```

Comment: Can you do the second one using a LET or INTO statement? the idea is that I need to embed this into an existing LINQ statement so I cannot create a new var seperatly.

Comment: @JSchwartz I don't understand the comment. Could you add to your question with more details and maybe an example of what you mean by "embed this into an existing LINQ statement"?

Comment: In your example, what is PartNames?

Comment: I have added FULL source code to the original post. The code I got from you added as "let a ...." as this is where i need to do my magic so that in the next select new GroupRecipe() part I have the proper data to play with

Comment: It looks like you were able to integrate the query into your larger query. What's the problem now? A big help would be if you could describe in English what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well it isn't working as-is mostly because I do not underwhat PartNames is supposed to be, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: In English - I have a set of Data (Recipe/Ingredients and much more). In the first part I find all Recipes and get their ingredients and display them ViewFullRecipe(). Then for each of these I find the ingredient and see if any other recipe has that ingrident and it is does I must show the entire receipe (this is the part I am struggling with)

Comment: So the second part of my answer is this (in English): given an ingredient (part), get all recipes that contain that ingredient. In the resulting `IEnumerable<T>`, the type `T` has an `ItemName` (recipe) and an `IEnumerable<string> PartNames` (ingredients in recipe).

Comment: Whereas this isn't exactly working for me it IS a solution for the problem I asked (my fault for being to vague) and as such this is a good and valid something for the problem being asked. Thanks for the time spent on it.